# Redis benchmark command - Does it allow to define value contents and datatype

Tags: redis

I am exploring the Redis benchmark tool and I looked at this web page: [How fast is Redis?](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)

I pick the below command for example:

```
$ ./redis-benchmark -r 1000000 -n 2000000 -t get,set,lpush,lpop -q
```

I see that we can specify the type of operations, such as get, set, lpush etc. However, how do we know what datatypes are being used for values in these operations? Also, is there a way to specify your own data that can be consumed by the benchmark command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do we know what datatypes are being used for values in these operations?

By default, `xxx` is used as value.

> is there a way to specify your own data that can be consumed by the benchmark command?

1. You can use the command line argument `-d` to specify the length of value, e.g. use `redis-benchmark -d 10` to use `xxxxxxxxxx`, i.e. 10 characters, as value.
2. You can explicitly specify the command that you want to test, e.g. use `redis-benchmark -n 10000 SET your-key your-value` to run `SET` command 10000 times.

Run `redis-benchmark --help` to see other options.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! One follow-up question. If I were to specify my own command (point 2 above), will it run with just one pair of values (your-key your-value) for 10000 times ? Can I not make it read these values from a dataset for each set command?

Comment: It will run with the given key-value pair. You CANNOT make it read from a dataset.